# How does a PDA compare two configurations of accepting histories?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability, undecidability, pushdown-automata

[image: A Snippet of the proof from the book]In Michael Sipser's book, they prove that ALL_CFG = { G | G is a CFG and L(G) = Σ∗ } is undecidable using accepting computation histories and PDAs. My question is how exactly (with details of implementation)does a PDA go on to compare two configurations and figure out that the first properly yields the second.

I know that the computation histories are encoded in a convenient manner (reversing), but I couldn't seem to figure out how and what the PDA **really** does.

Comment: What is "the mentioned language"?  Please [edit] your question to make it self-contained.    Please define all notation.  How do your question about comparing two configuration relate to the first sentence of your post?

Comment: What is "ALL_CFG"?  It would help to define this notation before using it.

Comment: The answer would be rather verbose to write. The idea is that you can check that the input is of the form $\#w\#w^R\#w\#w^R\# \ldots$, and you can extend this to have the various $w$'s slightly different, following the local computation rules of the Turing machine. Perhaps the original paper bothered to list all the details.

Comment: A few more details are in [Hendrik Jan's note](https://liacs.leidenuniv.nl/~hoogeboomhj/second/codingcomputations.pdf) (see Section 3). You can also check the original papers cited there.